# jQuery <select> first <option> not disabled

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm trying to play with a selection so that when the user selects a product from the dropdown it gets disabled because the actions taken will not be allowed more than once per product. That works, but if you click on the dropdown, it is still selected but disabled, and I want to auto choose the first available `<option>` that is not disabled in order to be able to have it selected, and end of story ;)
Any clue?

```
$('#product_name').find('option:not([disabled]):first-of-type');
$('#product_name').find('option:not([disabled]):first-child');
$('#product_name').find('option:nth-child(1):not([disabled])');
```

Of course I have played around with `:not(:disabled)` too, but from my testing hours on this subject, the CSS selector works fine for elements NOT disabled but when the second `parameter === requisite` comes into play, that would be "selecting the first one matching the rule" everything gets dark and just don't work.

Comment: I think `option:not(:disabled):first` should do it. You're not doing anything with any of the selectors in the code you posted.

Comment: Could you post some real code that shows what you're trying to do with the result of the selection?

Comment: Yes, you right, I did not post any code as it was not necessary. I would use the .val() method to get the option's value to have it selected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq( 0 ). It could also be
>   written as :lt( 1 ). While this matches only a single element,
>   :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent.

```js
$('select option:not([disabled]):first').addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option disabled>Disabled One</option>
  <option disabled>Disabled One</option>
  <option>Enabled One</option>
  <option>Enabled One</option>
  <option selected>Enabled One</option>
  <option disabled>Disabled One</option>
  <option disabled>Disabled One</option>
  <option>Enabled One</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I see the real problem, I wasn't having into account that :first is not exactly the same than :first-child or :first-of-type and in fact I have never used it, and thats why It wasn't working, :first is more suitable for targeting that single element I wanted to fetch.